# Creating a batch file to prompt for response and replace lines of text in a text or .ini file

Tags: batch-file, text, replace

I have gotten the batch file to work for the first line, however when I try to add an additional FOR loop to get the next line of text it actually copies or duplicates the text instead of replacing it.
currently the batch file will not even change the .txt file.
Code below --

```
::Find and Replace script allows the user to 
::define a file path, file name and a string 
::to find and replace so as to create a new file.
::
::Original file is backed up with an added extension of *.bak, in case
::the user finds the need to go back to the original.

@echo off
::Use the path from whence the script was executed as
::the Current Working Directory
set CWD=%~dp0

::***BEGIN MODIFY BLOCK***
::The variables below should be modified to the
::files to be changed and the strings to find/replace
::Include trailing backslash in _FilePath
set _FilePath=C:\
set _FileName=Password1.txt

::_WrkFile is the file on which the script will make
::modifications.
set /P Password="What is the admin Password?"
set /P AuditPassword="What is the Audit Password?"
set oldPass="cmspassword=Password1"
set OldAudit="existingauditingdbpassword=Password1"
set CMSAdmin="cmspassword="
set CMSAudit="existingauditingdbpassword="
set OldStr=%oldPass%
set OldStr2=%OldAudit%
set NewStr="%CMSAdmin%%Password%"
set NewStr2="%CMSAudit%%AuditPassword%"
::***END MODIFY BLOCK***

::Set a variable which is used by the
::search and replace section to let us
::know if the string to be modified was
::found or not.
set _Found=Not found

SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if not exist "%_FilePath%%_FileName%" goto :NotFound

echo Searching for %OldStr% string...
echo.
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%_FilePath%%_FileName%") do (
    set _LineChk=%%a
    if "!_LineChk!"==%OldStr% (
        SET _Found=Found 
        SET NewStr=!NewStr:^"=! 
        echo !NewStr!
        ) else (echo %%a)
        )>>"%_FilePath%%_FileName%" 2>&1

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%_FilePath%%_FileName%") do (
    set _LineChk=%%b
    if "!_LineChk!"==%OldStr2% (
        SET _Found=Found 
        SET NewStr2=!NewStr2:^"=! 
        echo !NewStr2!
        )
        )
echo.
:Exit       
exit /b
```

Comment: If your aim is to create an updated file depending on the contents of the original, you need to test the value of the files content, modify it accordingly, **output the modified line to a new file**, then replace the original file with the new version using rename. In your current script, it appears you're just appending modified lines to the file

Comment: Correct I am just having it read the lines as a "Find and Replace" it works for a single line thus a single "For" loop but if I add another loop to change another line it does not work.

Comment: You cannot read from a file, and write to the same file from a [tag:for-loop] like that. I also see no reason why you cannot perform the second replace within the original loop, instead of adding another one and thus doubling the work when it isn't necessary.

Comment: This code is actually already reading and writing to the same .txt file. I will try adding the second look into the first one and see if t works thank you @Compo

Comment: Technically, your first loop is both reading from and appending to a the same file. Do no do it! Anything goes wrong and you'll lose potentially both. Start by creating a backup, then read the backup, whilst writing to the original. Once you've verified that the original is correct, you can optionally delete the backup.

Comment: The original code i started with was to backup the file etc... but found that it was not backing up the file properly so I deleted that part of the code and went with just a straight append.@Compo how would change the code and can you show me please?